# how to validate textfield that allows . only once with in the textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 4 text fields in my application.

I validate my textfields as textfield allow `0,1,...9` and `.`,for that i write code as fallows

```
- (IBAction) textfield:(id)sender {

    if ([textfield.text length] > 0) {
        if ([textfield.text length] > 10){          
            textfield.text = [textfield.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    }
        else {
            //retrieve last character input from texfield           
            int I01 = [homevalue.text length];
            int Char01 = [homevalue.text characterAtIndex:I01-1];
            //check and accept input if last character is a number from 0 to 9
            if ( (Char01 < 46) || (Char01 > 57) || (Char01 == 47) ) {

                if (I01 == 1) {
                    textfield.text = nil;
                }
                else {

                    textfield.text = [homevalue.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, I01-1)];
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

It works fine, Now i need to validate that `.` allows only once with in the textfield.

eg: 123.45

According to my code if i place again `.` it is allowed.
 eg:123.45.678

But it wont allowed once i place . ,that textfield wont allowed.

ed:123.45678.

How can i done this,

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Mahesh can you make the question more clear.Its hard to tell what is your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this predicate for texts that start with a number like "23.67"

```
NSString *decimalRegex = @"[0-9]+([.]([0-9]+)?)?"; // @"[0-9]+[.][0-9]+";
NSPredicate *decimalTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", decimalRegex]; 
BOOL isValidDecimal = [decimalTest evaluateWithObject:[textField text]];
```

If you want to allow "." at the fist place like ".95" use the following regex,

```
NSString *decimalRegex = @"[0-9]*([.]([0-9]+)?)?"; //@"[0-9]*[.][0-9]+";
```

Your code should look like this,

```
- (IBAction)textfield:(id)sender {

    int textLength = [[textfield text] length];

    if (textLength > 0) {

        NSString *decimalRegex = @"[0-9]+([.]([0-9]+)?)?"; //@"[0-9]+[.][0-9]+";
        NSPredicate *decimalTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", decimalRegex]; 
        BOOL isValidDecimal = [decimalTest evaluateWithObject:[textField text]];

        if (!isValidDecimal) {

            NSString *text = [[textField text] substringToIndex:textLength - 1];
            [textfield setText:text] 
        }
    } 
}
```

I guess this should work! Give it a try!

Comment: You should place this in *textfield:(id)sender* method. I've edited my answer. Try that.

Comment: No it returns Nothing,if i use this code nothing will be printed in textfield

Comment: *textfield:(id)sender* method called every time the text changes? If so, change the regex as *@"[0-9]+([.][0-9]?)?"*. I have edited my code now.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this method

`- (NSRange)rangeOfCharacterFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)aSet options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)aRange`

on textfield.text as its a NSString only